# ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small only three numbers

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
create or replace FUNCTION "FNC_CALCULATE_MOD11" (P_VALOR IN NUMBER) 
  return number is
      Result number;
begin
DECLARE
  -- LOCAL VARIABLES HERE
    V_PROCESSO VARCHAR2(30);
    V_PESO NUMBER := 2;
    V_SOMA NUMBER := 0;
    V_RESTO NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN

  V_PROCESSO := TO_CHAR(P_VALOR);
  WHILE LENGTH(V_PROCESSO) < 6  --Popular com zeros no inicio até 6
  LOOP
        V_PROCESSO := '0'||V_PROCESSO;
  END LOOP;

--accuses error on this line

FOR I IN REVERSE 1 .. LENGTH(V_PROCESSO)
  LOOP
      V_SOMA := TO_CHAR (V_SOMA) + TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(V_PROCESSO,i,1))*V_PESO;
      IF V_PESO = 9 THEN  --repetir peso se for necessario
         V_PESO := 2;
      ELSE
         V_PESO := V_PESO + 1;
      END IF;
  END LOOP;

  V_RESTO := MOD(V_SOMA, 11);
  Result := 11 - V_RESTO;

  IF ((Result = 0) OR (Result = 1) OR (Result >= 10)) THEN
     Result := 1;
  END IF;   

END;

  return(Result);
end FNC_CALCULATE_MOD11;
```

Comment: Add code as text not as link to an image

Comment: I will put the code and the error message

Comment: **ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1 ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small ORA-06512: at line 16 ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error ORA-06512: at "APPBRB.FNC_CALCULATE_MOD11", line 20**

Comment: Hmmm, your code seems to work. Here is [a demo on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=3a99fc94f0b2c4a3669b4b94ead2fa98). Please post the input data which produces that error.

Comment: Null parameter throws error, otherwise it seems to work.

Comment: Even filling data with the database returns null, 
how do I pair not return null?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `V_PROCESSO` to a bigger size, for example `V_PROCESSO VARCHAR2(300);`